# Retrieving payment confirmation from Paypal

Tags: php, payment, confirmation

I have a membership application form that collects basic demographic data. Once the form is submitted, I use PHP to insert the data into a database and then redirect the user to Paypal for membership payment. I would like to add a field to each user record that indicates whether or not a payment has been posted. Is there a way Paypal can pass back a confirmation that I can use to update each membership record?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check this out is called [IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) is provided by paypal, this is how it works  [image]